# HttpUrlConnection gives 400

Tags: android, http, httpurlconnection, webservice-client

Can anyone help me about this code block?

it is working with same params on Postman.

Parameters are true headers are true. But i think i am missing a configrations.

```
public String readJSONFeed() throws Exception {

    errorMessage = "";

    URL url;
    String response = "";
    try {
        url = new URL(uri);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", contentType);

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        if (contentType == "application/x-www-form-urlencoded") {
            writer.write(getPostDataString( params));

        }
        else {
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + SharedPrefManager.getInstance(context).getString(
                    SharedPrefManager.PREF_KEY_UserToken, ""
            ));
            conn.setRequestProperty("WWW-Authenticate", "Bearer");
            writer.write(new JSONObject(params).toString());
        }

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String line;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                response += line;
            }
        } else {
            response = "";

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;

}


   public String readJSONFeed() throws Exception {

    errorMessage = "";

    URL url;
    String response = "";
    try {
        url = new URL(uri);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", contentType);

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        if (contentType == "application/x-www-form-urlencoded") {
            writer.write(getPostDataString( params));

        }
        else {
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + SharedPrefManager.getInstance(context).getString(
                    SharedPrefManager.PREF_KEY_UserToken, ""
            ));
            conn.setRequestProperty("WWW-Authenticate", "Bearer");
            writer.write(new JSONObject(params).toString());
        }

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String line;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                response += line;
            }
        } else {
            response = "";

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;

}


  public String readJSONFeed() throws Exception {

    errorMessage = "";

    URL url;
    String response = "";
    try {
        url = new URL(uri);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", contentType);

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        if (contentType == "application/x-www-form-urlencoded") {
            writer.write(getPostDataString( params));

        }
        else {
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + SharedPrefManager.getInstance(context).getString(
                    SharedPrefManager.PREF_KEY_UserToken, ""
            ));
            conn.setRequestProperty("WWW-Authenticate", "Bearer");
            writer.write(new JSONObject(params).toString());
        }

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String line;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                response += line;
            }
        } else {
            response = "";

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;

}

  public String readJSONFeed() throws Exception {

    errorMessage = "";

    URL url;
    String response = "";
    try {
        url = new URL(uri);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", contentType);

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        if (contentType == "application/x-www-form-urlencoded") {
            writer.write(getPostDataString( params));

        }
        else {
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + SharedPrefManager.getInstance(context).getString(
                    SharedPrefManager.PREF_KEY_UserToken, ""
            ));
            conn.setRequestProperty("WWW-Authenticate", "Bearer");
            writer.write(new JSONObject(params).toString());
        }

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String line;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                response += line;
            }
        } else {
            response = "";

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;

}
```

Comment: is your contentType correct ??

Comment: @ik024 yes, it is same with postman